# Trying to prove $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \iff \sum\limits_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p} \left(\frac{x^3-x}{p} \right)=0$

Tags: summation, algebraic-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $p>2$ be a prime number. I would like to show that

> $$p \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \iff \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p} \left(\dfrac{x^3-x}{p} \right)=0$$

where $\left(\dfrac{\cdot}{p} \right)$ denotes the Legendre symbol mod $p$.

I know that $\sum_{y\in\mathbb{F}_p} \left(\dfrac{y}{p} \right)=0$, but here $y(x)= x^3-x$ doesn't give a bijection $\Bbb F_p \to \Bbb F_p$ (otherwise we would have been done).
I was trying to use the multiplicativity of Legendre symbol, but a factorization like $x(x-1)(x+1)$ didn't help me a lot.

Any comment would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: One direction follows with the map $x \mapsto p-x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you! The direction $\implies$ is done.

Comment: The other direction follows from the same symmetry. That Legendre symbol vanishes exactly when $x\equiv0,\pm1$. But when $p\equiv1\pmod4$ we know that $-1$ is a quadaratic residue, and therefore the contribution of any other pair $x$ and $-x$ is $\equiv2\pmod4$. Summing it  all up shows that the sum is then $\equiv p-3\not\equiv0\pmod4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the transformation $x \mapsto p-x$, we find

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \biggl(\frac{x^3-x}{p}\biggr) = \sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p} \biggl(\frac{-1}{p}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{x^3-x}{p}\biggr).$$

For $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, we have $\bigl(\frac{-1}{p}\bigr) = -1$, and it follows that the sum is $0$. For $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, the transformation shows that

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \biggl(\frac{x^3-x}{p}\biggr) = 2\sum_{x = 1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \biggl(\frac{x^3-x}{p}\biggr).$$

But since $1^3 - 1 = 0$, we have

$$\sum_{x = 1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \biggl(\frac{x^3-x}{p}\biggr) = \sum_{x = 2}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \biggl(\frac{x^3-x}{p}\biggr) \equiv 1 \pmod{2},$$

so the sum over all $x$ does not vanish.